# Conditional logic within templates depending on route

Tags: ember.js

I'm wondering if conditional blocks can be used in a template that depend on the resource/route you're currently in. It would be very useful when accessing nested routes that use the same templates.

*More Details*

I have a resource called "user" and nested in that resource is route called "edit":

```
// Read single user
this.resource('user', {path:'/user/:UserID'}, function(){

  // Update / Delete existing user
  this.route('edit');

});
```

I know I can use {{outlet}} in the "user" template and it will render the "user/edit" template but I'd like to used conditional statements within the user template.

For example:

```
{{if route is user}}
<h2>View User</h2>
{{/if}}
{{if route is user/edit}}
<h2>Edit User</h2>
{{/if}}
```

Is this possible?

Thanks,
Tom

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but it is not recommended as the same result can be achieved with less code, and be less bug prone by using the {{outlet}} in the user template.

If you still insist on using the anti-pattern you suggested, what I would do is use the activate/deactivate hooks on the UserEditRoute to set/unset an "isInEditMode" property on the userController instance, and use the template conditional on that property.

I don't want to put a sample code as this is a bad practice, and I don't want anyone to use it.

Sorry.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out as bad practice! Still getting my head round the best way to achieve things in Ember. I essentially wanted to show an an edit button when I was in "user" and hide it when I was in user.edit but it's overkill and I could always use separate templates. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Meori is right. If you nest your routes you should also nest your templates via `{{outlet}}`. If you want different templates to be rendered, you should not nest your routes.

So maybe you want to go with something like that:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
  this.resource('user', { path: '/user/:UserID' });
  this.route('user.edit', { path: '/user/:UserID/edit' });
});
```

And then you can have different templates for displaying and editing a user.